# JavaScript: Use forEach within higher order function to manipulate / add to each element in array Error: undefined return

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, return, higher-order-functions

I am trying to add 10 to every element in an Array using forEach.  But when I push and then return my new array it gives me back undefined.

Below is my code:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];

function changeArray(array, inputFunc) {

  //console.log(array)

  let output = [];

  array.forEach((ele) => {
    return output.push(ele + 10);
  });
}

changeArray(array)
```

Expected Return: [11, 12, 13]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not returning `output` anywhere. If you `return output` after your foreach, you get the desired result.

Comment: `return output.push(ele + 10);` – `return` doesn’t do anything there.

Comment: What is `inputFunc` for? You never use it.

Comment: Also, even if the return value were used, `push()` doesn't return what you think it does. It returns the new length of the array, not the element that was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return output` from the final function - `forEach` doesn't return anything, and doesn't do anything with returned values from inside the callback passed.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

function changeArray(array, inputFunc) {

  let output = [];
  array.forEach((ele) => {
    output.push(ele + 10);
  });
  
  return output;
  
}

console.log(changeArray(array));
```

You could also use `map` for more concise code:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

function changeArray(array, inputFunc) {
  return array.map(e => e + 10);  
}

console.log(changeArray(array));
```